# what is best way to augment a cycle with shortcut edges to minimize the sum of distances?

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory, given a cycle with $n$ vertices (and $m=n$ edges), suppose that we have a budget of additional $m'$ edges that can be used as shortcuts in the cycle. What is the best way to place those shortcuts so as the minimize the sum of distances in the resulting graph?  Is there a simple answer if $m'$ is small, say, $m' < n-5$?

Comment: It seems to me that if $m' \ge \binom k2$, for some maximal $k$, you should choose $k$ equally spaced (or as close as possible) vertices and use the extra edges to build a complete $k$-graph on them. Subtract off $\binom k2$ from $m'$ and repeat with a new lower value of $k$, this time chosing your $k$ vertices to be the mid points of equally spaced gaps in the original pick of vertices. Keep going until $m'$ is zero.

Comment: If $m' \geq n-3$, then every graph containing a star is optimal, as it will be of width 2, and the number of pair of vertices with distance 1 is exactly the number of edges. It seems possible to find width 2 graphs by adding only $n-4$ edges (at least up to $n=9$)

Comment: @PaulSinclair would you have a pointer/reference or additional insight to your rationale?

Comment: @caduk thanks! what about $m' < n-4$ ? would you have any insight about how to extend your idea? by the way, the width of a graph is its diameter?

Comment: It is my own idea (thus "It seems to me"), so I have no reference. Also "seems" was to indicate that I have no proof that it is optimal. But even if it isn't, it ought to be close. I think I can prove that if $m' = \binom k2$ for some $k$, then it is optimal. But what to do with any excess edges beyond that is not as clear.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No idea for the moment. I just realized that my solution with $n=9$ have $6$ new edges, and I'm not sure we can continue further with $n-4$. I feel like for small $m'$, we should take long cords, and for larger $m'$, put all edges on one vertex, but I'm not sure... We should do some brute force calculation to get a feel  (I don't have the time for this this we).